# Equivalent batch script for bash script

Tags: windows, bash, batch-file, awk, find

I have a bash script which is used to get the number of disks present on a machine.

```
echo "rescan" > $script
echo "list disk" >> $script
disks=$($diskpart /s $script | tee ${logfile} | awk '$1 == "Disk" && ($3 == "Online" || $3 == "Offline") {print $2}')
```

Im trying to do the same for a Windows machine. I have the following script for the same:

```
echo > script.txt rescan
echo >> script.txt list disk
```

But Im not sot sure on how to proceed for the next step of using awk in a batch script.
Can you suggest on how to get the value of disks in a batch script. Im very new to batch scipting.

I have searched for a while and found that the equivalent for awk is "FOR /F", But im not sure how to use the same in my current situation

Comment: What flavour of windows are you running?

Comment: It is windows 2008 R2

Comment: does it have to be batch or maybe powershell is okay for this too? I suppose piping and stuff should be easiser to translate to ps instead of batch...

Comment: unfortunately it has to be batch script only

Answer (score 0):

Under `Windows Vista`, `Windows 7` and `Windows XP Pro` you should be able to use the `Windows Management Instrumentation command` (wmi) to do this:

```
WMIC LOGICALDISK GET DEVICEID, VOLUMENAME
```

Here is a link explaining how to list different kind of information using [wmic](http://en.code-bude.net/2013/02/23/show-all-drives-in-command-prompt/)

Comment: I need to get the value of disks as in the bash file.... when "list disks" is run

Comment: @Pradeep - I must get going, but I will try to update my answer when I come back.